# Pass php Laravel's APP_URL value to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I use AngularJS in my Laravel app.

In AngularJS, I use:

```
$location.host()
```

to get the domain of my app (e.g: www.example.com) and get access to my API, e.g:

```
var url = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + "/api/products/" ;
```

Now I changed servers and my main app location went from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/here`. `$location.host()` gives me `www.example.com`, but not the `/here` part.

I am trying to find a way to use Laravel's APP_URL value (which contains my main app location) and pass it to AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module("appProducts"); 
app.controller("CtrlUserSchedule", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $location, $modal) {

    --> var laravelUrl = ** get php APP_URL value here **;

        var apiUrl = laravelUrl + "/api/products/" ;
```

What's the cleanest way to pass APP_URL to AngularJS. Is there a way to set it globally so APP_URL is available in all my AngularJS apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about simply printint it out in the header?

```
<script>
window.app_url = {{env('APP_URL')}}
</script>
</head>
```

Then it will simply be accessible from window.app_url or app_url after that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but it works for me

```
In blade
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _url= {{env('APP_URL')}};
</script>

In Angular Module
angular.module('testAPp', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.url= _url;
    });
```

Now you can use $rootScope.url in angular controller as

```
var app = angular.module("appProducts"); 
app.controller("CtrlUserSchedule", ['$scope','$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$modal', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $modal) {
        var apiUrl = $rootScope.url + "/api/products/" ;
```

Comment: Excellent solution too. Thanks!